Regain Belgian Nationality
I have been a Belgian citizen since childhood and completed my studies in Belgium. After getting married, I moved to Canada and acquired Canadian citizenship. Recently, I was informed by the Belgian authorities that I lost my Belgian nationality. To regain it, I am required to work and live in Belgium for at least one year. However, due to my current inability to work, I am seeking alternative options to regain my Belgian nationality. My entire family resides in Belgium, and I visit them twice a year for a total period of 2 to 4 months. What other possibilities are available for me to regain my Belgian nationality under these circumstances?
Thank you!

Why did you lose it? What did the civil registrar in the municipality where your family reside say about other options when you contacted them?

Also when did you gain your Canadian citizenship?

No other options. Just work and pay taxes.
I obtained my Canadian citizenship in 1999

Have you read the Wikipedia article?  If it is correct, you just need to reside in Belgium, not necessarily work (if you can afford not to work for a year -- which might be the case if, for example, you have some disability support in Canada that would continue even after you move to Belgium).

Yes, I have read the Wikipedia article and I am registered at the municipality in Brussels. I need to reside in Belgium for one year, but I require a Belgian ID card, which the commune is not providing.
With my Canadian passport, I can't stay in Belgium for more than three months, open a bank account, or access any services without a Belgian ID card. I also do not receive disability support from Canada.
I have been trying to resolve this issue for the past six years without any guidance from the commune. I am unsure how to proceed.
